# Do the War Domain cleric's Channel Divinity options Guided Strike and War God's Blessing stack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, cleric, stacking

The [War Domain cleric](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#WarDomain) has the [Channel Divinity option *Guided Strike*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ChannelDivinity:GuidedStrike-161) (PHB, p. 63):

> Starting at 2nd level, you can use your Channel Divinity to strike with supernatural accuracy. When you make an attack roll, you can use your Channel Divinity to gain a +10 bonus to the roll. You make this choice after you see the roll, but before the DM says whether the attack hits or misses.

The [Channel Divinity option *War God's Blessing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#ChannelDivinity:WarGod%E2%80%99sBlessing-162) allows an identical benefit to extend to another creatures:

> At 6th level, when a creature within 30 feet of you makes an attack roll, you can use your reaction to grant that creature a +10 bonus to the roll, using your Channel Divinity. You make this choice after you see the roll, but before the DM says whether the attack hits or misses.

If two War Domain clerics were in the same party, and one uses *Guided Strike* to add +10 to their attack roll, could the other War Domain cleric use *War God's Blessing* to add a further +10 to that attack roll?

Or would they not stack, as they are the same source (i.e. a War Domain cleric's Channel Divinity)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### They Stack.

[Rules for combining game effects from the DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects):

> when two or more game features **have the same name**, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. (DMG, pg. 252)

Channel Divinity is not the name of these class features, at least, not the full name. Because *Guided Strike* and *War God’s Blessing* have different names, they stack.

As an example that falls in the same category that would more intuitively be ruled in the same way, imagine a Grassland Druid and a Cleric caste *haste* and *warding bond* respectively, on the same target. Naturally, we would rule that the target gets +3 AC, even though the two spells come from class features of the same name, “Spellcasting”.